# which layout engine for finding coordinates of html elements on the web page?

Tags: c++, html, webkit, gecko

I am doing some web data classification task and was thinking if I could get the **co-ordinates of html elements as they would appear on a web-browser** without taking into consideration any     css or javascript being referred in the web page.

My **language of programming is c++** and the need results for a couple million of pages, so it has to be fast. I know there is a Microsoft COM component which renders the page in a web browser control and then can be queried for position of different html tags. But this is not suitable in my case as it first renders the whole page which takes up a lot of time.

So as I found out, there are open-source layout engines WebKit, Gecko that can probably be used for this. But that's a huge piece of code and I need someone to direct me to the right classes or right modules to look into or any previous/similar work someone has done previously. Also, please let me know what you guys think is a good choice if I want to customize the existing code for use with multiple threads to make it faster.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you have the problem of HTML itself not specifying layout details then (i.e. it all depends on the defaults of the layout engine)?

Comment: Maybe I forgot to put this, relative position of elements with respect to each other is more important in my case and if you notice, most browsers render web pages in an almost similar way. So it doesn't really matter which rendering engine is used but important is that I get the position coordinates of elements that it renders.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you would find that different page rendering engines do render the html in their own way and the results will differ.

The thing is that if you stick to any concrete browser engine, what you are to do is somehow bringing this engine into your project and using engine's interface to retrieve these coordinates. Kind of a tough task though, simply because you'll have to read a lot of documentation and crawl through thousands of files.

I think that right approach would be posting this task in some place, that is specific for the page rendering engine you've chosen. (gecko/webkit/...)

If you prefer sticking to something MS-specific, guess it's gonna be easier, but can't help you with something like class names or code chunks that you want to see. Probably somebody else could guide you in this case.

Comment: as I mentioned, it is not important which rendering engine is being used  or if they render it differently, but position of elements that it will render and how easy it would be to integrate in my code. And I agree, my results would be biased coz of the engine I use..I think it is a good idea to post in respective forums..but I am still open to further comments and suggestions..Thanks

Comment: Hm, forgot to mention... I'm not quite sure about your actual aim, but I think, that before digging into web engines' code you should actually think about all these differences between renderers. Cause even in case of simple html web-designers often make different layouts, apply fixes for different browsers, etc... Imagine how different will the rendering look, when, e.g JavaScript is involved. Even window width or enabling / disabling of your browser's toolbar could affect elements positioning. I guess this is the case where planning your application should take REALLY a lot of time